# Can't upgrade from erlang-R14B-04 to erlang-R16B-03

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, centos6

I want to install the latest RabbitMQ server 3.6.14 on CentOS 6.

I followed this tutorial: [How To Install and Manage RabbitMQ](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-rabbitmq)

When I ran the below command to install "erlang", it installed the "erlang-R14B-04" package and not "erlang >= R16B-03" required to install RabbitMQ 3.6.14.

```
# yum install erlang
```

So I tried to uninstall erlang by running

`# yum remove erlang`

And when I downloaded and tried to install "erlang >= R16B-03" from a .rpm file, I encountered the following errors:

```
Transaction Check Error:
      file /usr/bin/epmd from install of esl-erlang-R16B03-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package erlang-erts-R14B-04.3.el6.x86_64
      file /usr/bin/erl from install of esl-erlang-R16B03-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package erlang-erts-R14B-04.3.el6.x86_64
      file /usr/bin/erlc from install of esl-erlang-R16B03-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package erlang-erts-R14B-04.3.el6.x86_64
      file /usr/bin/escript from install of esl-erlang-R16B03-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package erlang-erts-R14B-04.3.el6.x86_64
      file /usr/bin/run_erl from install of esl-erlang-R16B03-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package erlang-erts-R14B-04.3.el6.x86_64
      file /usr/bin/run_test from install of esl-erlang-R16B03-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package erlang-erts-R14B-04.3.el6.x86_64
      file /usr/bin/to_erl from install of esl-erlang-R16B03-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package erlang-erts-R14B-04.3.el6.x86_64
      file /usr/bin/dialyzer from install of esl-erlang-R16B03-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package erlang-dialyzer-R14B-04.3.el6.x86_64
      file /usr/bin/typer from install of esl-erlang-R16B03-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package erlang-typer-R14B-04.3.el6.x86_64

Error Summary
```

To deal with them, I removed the mentioned files: epmd, erl, erlc, escript, run_erl, run_test, to_erl, dialyzer, and typer after backing them up.

But still I face the same error. How do I upgrade from erlang-R14B-04 to erlang-R16B-03? Please help.

Comment: Have you tried removing all of the mentioned rpm packages that are conflicting? `yum remove erlang-erts-R14B-04.3.el6.x86_64; yum remove erlang-dialyzer-R14B-04.3.el6.x86_64; yum remove erlang-typer-R14B-04.3.el6.x86_64`.

Comment: you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 1):

Download the package:

```
wget https://github.com/rabbitmq/erlang-rpm/releases/download/v20.3.0/erlang-20.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

then install

```
yum install erlang-20.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```